# Filesystem c++, geting no output. Avoiding static compiling?

Tags: c++, std, cout, static-linking

I'm having problems getting any output from the `std::filesystem` functions in `C++`, even from the most simple functions like `current_path`. I'm compiling with `mingw64, g++` on Windows, it comes with `C++17` support and experimental `C++20` support which I've enabled, but regardless of `C++` version, I'm getting no output. This is the `tasks.json` I'm using with Visual Studio code:

```
"type": "cppbuild",
"label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
"command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
"args": [
    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "-std=gnu++20"
],
"options": {
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
},
"problemMatcher": [
    "$gcc"
],  
"group": "build",
"detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
```

I've tried running some very simple examples from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path), such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Current path is " << fs::current_path() << '\n'; // (1)
    fs::current_path(fs::temp_directory_path()); // (3)
    std::cout << "Current path is " << fs::current_path() << '\n';
}
```

Which returns no output at all. Another thing I wanted to do was listing the files in a certain directory [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string path = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop";
    for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
}
```

Which again, returns absolutely no output. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I've not been able to find anybody else with this problem.

While writing the question I've found an answer that works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789294/no-output-from-c-program), that is, adding the `-static` argument to `g++` to avoid dynamic linking. I'm not familiar with these minutiae yet, but is there no way to avoid static building in my case?

Comment: Try running your program from the explorer with a double-click. See it you get any error messages. Also try running from the MSYS terminal (the `mingw64.exe` one).

Comment: yeah, I cannot reproduce this (but then again, I'm using a mac, so... yeah).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, when running through explorer by double clicking everything works fine without static building! Why doesn't it output anything when running through the regular terminal? What is happening?

Comment: The difference has to be in the PATH.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've followed the instructions at [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) and added `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to my path, nothing else. What should I be looking for?

Comment: try using [dependency walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to see which DLLs your executable requires

Comment: @AlanBirtles this is what i get: https://imgur.com/kOntFZa . Sorry but I'm not quite sure what to look for.

Comment: you need to make sure the gcc dlls are available on your path. Your application seems to be crashing or not starting, you need to use a debugger or at least look at the return code of your application to find out why

Comment: Perhaps related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208442/c-program-using-filesystem-library-just-does-nothing-on-windows

Comment: @orhtej2 that seems to be it. I've reproduced the steps the answer suggests and `cygpath -w /mingw64` returns a path from the python distribution `anaconda`. So I guess @HolyBlackCat was right, something is wrong with the path. I'll look into it and eventually update the question.