# std::filesystem::path causes crash with C++20 built dll under Windows 11

Tags: c++, windows, c++20, std-filesystem

I build a dll with functions to be used in an exe which I currently mock. Both bins build correctly but the problem emerges when there's
`std::filesystem::path` variable declared in imported function:

**dll mylib.h**

```cpp
namespace mylib
{
MYLIB_EXPORT void foo(const std::string& bar) noexcept;
}
```

**dll mylib.cpp**

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace mylib
{
void foo(const std::string& bar) noexcept
{
    std::filesystem::path pathToFile(bar); // problematic line
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;
}
}
```

**mock main.cpp**

```
#include "mylib.h"

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "MockEntry" << std::endl;
    std::string path{"foo"};
    mylib::foo(path);
    std::cout << "MockExit" << std::endl;
}
```

The dll is linked properly but running mock.exe produces no output in terminal, only under gdb the result is:

```bash
(gdb) run
Starting program: .../mock.exe
[New Thread 30948.0x6490]
[New Thread 30948.0x7a84]
[New Thread 30948.0x11d4]
[Thread 30948.0x64b4 exited with code 3221225785]
[Thread 30948.0x11d4 exited with code 3221225785]
[Thread 30948.0x7a84 exited with code 3221225785]
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.
```

When I comment out the line:

```cpp
    // std::filesystem::path pathToFile(bar); problematic line
```

everything runs as expected and the output is:

```bash
MockEntry
foo
MockExit
```

The tools I use are CMake, ninja, gcc 13.2 (MinGW). C++20 enabled in CMake.

I have tried to build minimalistic executable using filesystem with

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    std::filesystem::path{"bar.txt"};
    std::cout << "foo2" << std::endl;
}
```

and minimalistic CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/ProgramData/mingw64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe")
project(blank
  LANGUAGES CXX)

set (NAME blank)

set(SOURCES
  main.cpp)
  
add_executable(${NAME} ${SOURCES})
```

and the result is the same - crash.

Help will be much appreciated as I can't sort out the problem.

Comment: `0xc0000139` means you're missing a dll

Comment: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xc0000139](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xc0000139) "STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND: {Entry Point Not Found} The procedure entry point %hs could not be located in the dynamic link library %hs."  Possible [Dll Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) caused by having an incompatible dll of the same name in a folder of your `PATH` environment variable ahead of the correct dll.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208442/c-program-using-filesystem-library-just-does-nothing-on-windows 
This was the problem. Despite I set everything in PATH, CMAKE etc. for MinGW64 installed by choco, ninja executed in git bash repeatedly linked the program to bash's own libstdc++ which must have slightly different ABI. I find this annoying that the packages/tools don't report their versions of MinGW by setting PATH or environment variables on Windows but maybe there is a reason behind this.